# C# MongoDB: How to do a find query with min and max?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this MongoDB console command:

```
db.transactions.find({itemid: 1234}).min({time: 1608526637000}).max({time: 1608525314845}).hint({time: -1})
```

and I would like to turn this to a C# code with MongoDB's C# driver. This is similar to a query that uses `$gte` and `$lte` operators, in that both queries will return transactions within the given time period. However, using the `$gte` and `$lte` query took ~5 secs while the min/max query took less than 0.5 secs.

With such a substantial time difference, I'd be a fool not to use the faster method. However, I can't seem to find how to do queries with min/max functions in C#. Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

**Additional info**: Both the `itemid` and `time` fields are indexed, and I am running this query over 100 million documents.

Comment: How big is the collection you're running this on? Even on a collection with almost 200,000 documents, and a fairly complicated query, I don't see anywhere like the times you're talking about. You do have appropriate indexes, right?

Comment: I have both itemid and time indexed, and am running this over 100 million documents.

Comment: When you say you have them both indexed, is it one composite index or two separate indexes?

Comment: @John That seems to have been it! I was using the MongoDB Compass, and I guess I just assumed that it'll work as expected as long as the indexes are there. I still wonder though, how did the min/max functions do that query much faster even without compounded index?

Comment: I am curious about that myself. I guess you'd need to run an explain to get insight into that.

Comment: @John Surprisingly enough, `explain()` didn't explain much difference between the two. The `indexName` for the min/max query was `time_-1` while for the other, it's the compounded index. The `explain()` for min/max query is quite barren, and the min and max times weren't even mentioned. I do wonder the possibility of the min/max query being a legitimate replacement to gte/lte when it comes to ranges, but I guess I don't have the time to do further research on this. Anyways, thank you very much for pointing out that rookie mistake of mine!